# How can I get texture to the right place when I change texture in gltf format with Three.js?

Tags: javascript, graphics, three.js, 3d, gltf

I've tried to change the texture of glTF model dynamically by replacing the texture with `THREE.TextureLoader`. The color of the texture changed as I expected to, however the pattern of the texture was somewhat mixed.

This is my first time doing web graphics. I was remixing a 3d-model viewer example with three.js that can load glTF models. I wanted to change texture dynamically by buttons. From various kinds of formats, I chose glTF because it seemed like a new standard. The best solution I could found until now was to add `texture.flipY = false;` below my texture loader, but it didn't work. I also tried to change some values within the texture object, but nothing happened.

This is where I load my model:

```js
loader.load( urls, function (texture) {
    var pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( texture );
    pmremGenerator.update( renderer );

    var pmremCubeUVPacker = new THREE.PMREMCubeUVPacker(pmremGenerator.cubeLods);
    pmremCubeUVPacker.update( renderer );

    var envMap = pmremCubeUVPacker.CubeUVRenderTarget.texture;
    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader().setPath( `models/${modelName}/`);

    loader.load(`${modelName}.gltf`, (gltf) => {

        gltf.scene.traverse((child) => {
            if (child.isMesh) {
                child.material.envMap = envMap;
            }
        });

        gltf.scene.scale.set(0.01,0.01,0.01)
        scene.add(gltf.scene);
    });
```

and I tried to change it's texture by implementing this function:

```js
function changeColor(color) {

    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const texture = textureLoader.load(`models/${modelName}/textures/fabric-${color}.jpg`);

    texture.flipY = false;

    scene.traverse((child) => {
        if (child.isMesh) {
            if (child.material.map.format === 1022) {
                child.material.map = texture;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Although I was able to target the mesh I wanted and changed it's color, the texture pattern was very awkward. It was top part of the chair, made with fabric.

to draw it in text, it seemed like this...

What it was meant to be:

```
-------------------
| / / / / / / / / |
| / / / / / / / / |
| / / / / / / / / |
| / / / / / / / / |
| / / / / / / / / |
| / / / / / / / / |
| / / / / / / / / |
-------------------
Figure 1
```

Reality:

```
-------------------
|      +++++      |
|      +++++      |
| ++++++++++++++  |
| ++++++++++++++  |
| ++++++++++++++  |
|      +++++      |
|      +++++      |
-------------------
Figure 2
```

To be clear:
How can I reserve the pattern of the texture like figure 1, when changing the texture file by the function above?

Comment: While I like the ASCII illustrations, it's a bit hard to know what you're seeing here. ;) You're correct in setting `flipY=false`. Beyond that, does the model have a texture initially that you're changing? Or no texture built in, but you're adding it? If the meshes in the model do not have UVs (`mesh.geometry.attributes.uv`) that'll be a problem. Typically the UV mapping is how you control where a texture sits on the mesh, and that's best done in a tool like Blender.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy sorry for my poor drawing :( if you don't mind, you can visit [this link](http://jskoo.kr/3d-viewer-min/) to see how it looks like. Yes the model have a texture initially, and I was trying to just change the `material.map` with new JPG file that I colored differently. I'll try something with UV mappings. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to DonMcCurdy's help, I finally got the answer.

It was indeed a problem with UV mapping.

To get texture in the right place, I needed to add these: wrapS, wrapT, and RepeatWrapping

```js
function changeColor(color) {

    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const texture = textureLoader.load(`models/${modelName}/textures/fabric-${color}.jpg`);

    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.flipY = false;

    scene.traverse((child) => {
        if (child.isMesh) {
            if (child.material.map.format === 1022) {
                child.material.map = texture;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Official documentation:
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture